# Allow drivers execution while rendering on google colab

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, scripting, drivers

I use [Google Colab](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html), specifically [blender-colab on github](https://github.com/ynshung/blender-colab) to render a scene, but in the scene I use some drivers to show/hide some objects at certain time. By default blender on colab turns off auto script execution, disabling the drivers. How can I fix that?

https://github.com/ynshung/blender-colab

Comment: btw the script I am using https://github.com/ynshung/blender-colab

Comment: You need to add '-y' or '--enable-autoexec` to the [command line](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options) in the colab script.